# Can I get Directx 10/11 working on Ubuntu 14.04 or higher?

Tags: 14.04, games, steam, microsoft

I have been searching the internet for a while now looking for a way to install and get directx 10/11 working in Ubuntu so that I can play games that need directx 10/11, like Just Cause 2, and a lot of Steam games. I am just looking to see if it is possible at all to get directx 10/11 working in Ubuntu. If not, do you have any ideas when or if there will be a way? Thx

Comment: Pretty sure the only way to get directx to install is via wine. Have you tried installing and playing the game via playonlinux?

Answer (score 1):

DirectX is a collection of a runtime *and drivers*.  As Wine does not support the installation of Micro$oft Windows drivers, you *cannot install just any version of DirectX.*  **:-(**

Therefore, DirectX support needs to be enabled inside the Wine environment by the Wine developers.

For more info on the current development of DirectX under wine, [read this wine FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Does_Wine_support_DirectX.3F_Should_I_install_Microsoft.27s_DirectX_under_Wine.3F).

<sub>(DirectX9 supported at the time of this writing, DirectX10 being planned)</sub>

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**